# require composer's phptimer vendor

Tags: php, composer-php

My code is the composer phptimer function. I would like to run it to see if it works only when I go to the page the code is on it returns a 500 internal error. I think it has to do with the require. How should I properly include the autoload file? It is in:
puplic_html->phptimer->vendor->autoload.php

```
<?php
require '/phptimer/vendor/autoload.php'
PHP_Timer::start();
print("-------OUTPUT------");
$time = PHP_Timer::stop();
var_dump($time);
print PHP_Timer::secondsToTimeString($time);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on the second line. If it won't help enable error_reporting. Also check your path because I think it may cause next problems. I advise you to use relative path, now php should treat your path as absolute.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relative path? relative to the root? I works now with the path I used above.